# How to get a config node's variables in the parent node?

Tags: node.js, node-red

Imagine I have a node in Node-RED that uses a config node called `my-config-node` as its property. I want to customize my label function so it display the `my-config-node`'s variable `myVar`.

Normally I would use `RED.nodes.getNode` (as shown below) and pass the node id, but it seems it is not available.

```
label: function () {
  // RED.nodes.getNode is not available here
  const myConfig = RED.nodes.getNode(this.my-config-node)
  return this.name || 'myConfig:' + (myConfig ? myConfig.myVar : '')
}
```

How can I get to a variable of a config node from the node that is using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the editor, you can use the `RED.nodes.node()` function to retrieve the config node:

```
label: function () {
  const myConfig = RED.nodes.node(this.my-config-node)
  return this.name || 'myConfig:' + (myConfig ? myConfig.myVar : '')
}
```